# How to access Livy on a Kerberized cluster (or disable Kerberos for Livy)?

Tags: kerberos, livy

I created an AWS EMR cluster with Kerberos enabled, and I am able to authenticate Hadoop with my Kerberos keytab using the Java hadoop.conf authentication method. However, I cannot access Livy as I keep running into this error:

HTTP ERROR: 401
Problem accessing /. Reason:
    Authentication required

I cannot find a way online to authenticate Livy in my code, the only relevant module is requests_kerberos but it requires an existing valid TGT. I am looking for a way to be able to pass in a keytab or principal name+password to authenticate Livy.

If this is not possible, how can I disable Kerberos for Livy without affecting other components like Hadoop?

Comment: You can't and you don't have to. Any serious HTTP client supports **SPNego** i.e. Kerberos-on-HTTP, out of the box.

Comment: Note that for performance reasons the SPNego challenge/response should be done only once on the beginning of the session; after that there's a session cookie available.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate to livy via Kerberos, you need the following pre-conditions:

1. The user you are authenticating to must exist in **all nodes** (see createlinuxusers.sh)
2. You need to create a kerberos principal for the user in the master node (see configurekdc.sh)

[For more information, can check out AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/securing-data-analytics-with-an-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-and-kerberized-amazon-emr-cluster/)

**Note that there is a bug in the cloudformation template which changes the sparkmagic config.json file.**

You need to revert this section

```
"authenticators": {
    "Kerberos": "sparkmagic.auth.kerberos.Kerberos",
    "Kerberos": "sparkmagic.auth.customauth.Authenticator",
    "Basic_Access": "sparkmagic.auth.basic.Basic"
  }
```

to its original state

```
"authenticators": {
    "Kerberos": "sparkmagic.auth.kerberos.Kerberos",
    "None": "sparkmagic.auth.customauth.Authenticator",
    "Basic_Access": "sparkmagic.auth.basic.Basic"
  }
```